# Nonlinear Schrödinger blow-up for non radial solutions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, blow-ups

I am studying a paper of Frank Merle and Pierre Raphaël,
http://math.unice.fr/~praphael/Publications/blow-up-norme-critique.pdf.
The equations are
$$
i\partial_tu+\Delta u=-|u|^{p-1}u
$$
on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 3$, $\dfrac{n+3}{n-1}\leq p<\dfrac{n+2}{n-2}$. They prove that for every radial initial condition $u_0\in \dot{H^1}\cap \dot{H^s}$, $\left(s=\dfrac{n}{2}-\dfrac{2}{p-1}\right)$ of negative energy
$$
E(u_0)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u_0(x)|^2dx-\frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u_0(x)|^{p+1}\leq 0
$$

the solution of the equation blows up in finite time $T\in (0,\infty)$, and there existe $\alpha>0$ such that
$$
\Vert u\Vert_{\dot{H^s}}\geq \log(T-t)
$$
for all $t$ close to $T$.
My question was to ask if the same result had been proved for non radial solutions, because in the proof, they rely heavily on the radial structure (see for example radial Gagliardo-Nirenberg  lemma 2, or (3.35)), and it doesn't seem obvious to generalize this result.

Comment: I assume you have, but just in case,  you may want to check who cited their result.

Comment: There is very clearly a typo in your statement of the result, since $n+3 \not\leq n+2$. I am having trouble accessing Pierre's webpage right now (it is not responding), but I am assuming you are talking about the [AJM paper from 2008?](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2427005)

Comment: The blow-up result by itself is not so much the emphasis of the paper, by the way. If you are willing to consider more regular initial data (which gives you (weighted) $L^2$ control) the finite-time blow-up result (not needing radial symmetry) is classical and due to Glassey in '77 (among others). In some ways Theorem 2 (the log time lower bound) of the paper is much more interesting than Theorem 1, and I am not aware of generalisations to the non-radial case.

Comment: Thank you M. Wong, I corrected the typo. And it is indeed the article you are mentioning. After more careful research, there does not seem to be any generalisation of this result to the non-radial case. (I don't want to consider more regular data, just non-radial ones).